# iOS push notifications - UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization - permission not granted - why?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Here's my code:

```
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
        ....
    }
```

I get `false` for `granted`. Why?

Comment: Are you sure user granted your request?

Comment: @Monty Yes. Sometimes with multiple calls I can have a mixture of true and false. At the time of the question I was getting all true.

Comment: Try to print(error.localizedDescription), you can get what is actually issue.

Comment: @PaulMarshal there is no error. `granted` is false but there's no error.

Comment: @Questioner, Have you checked in app settings?  make sure previously permission was not denied.